# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

[image]

I'm trying to query UserMetaData for a single record using the following query

```
 using (JonTestDataEntities context = new JonTestDataEntities())
            {
                return context.UserMetaData.Single(user => user.User.ID == id);               
            }
```

The error I'm receiving is: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. It is trying to lazyload Group for UserMetaData record.  How can I change my query to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a strong type that matches the signature of your result set. Entity Framework is creating an anonymous type and the anonymous type is disposed after the using statement goes out of scope.

So assigning to a strong type avoids the issue altogether. I'd recommend creating a class called UserDTO since you're really creating a data transfer object in this case. The benefit of the dedicated DTO is you can include only the necessary properties to keep your response as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 3):

As the message says, you cannot lazily load it after the function returns, because you've already disposed the context. If you want to be able to access `Group`, you can make sure you fetch it earlier. The extension method `.Include(entity => entity.NavigationProperty)` is how you can express this:

```
using (JonTestDataEntities context = new JonTestDataEntities())
{
    return context.UserMetaData.Include(user => user.Group).Single(user => user.User.ID == id);
}
```

Also consider adding `.AsNoTracking()`, since your context will be gone anyway.

Comment: What if I don't want to load Group?

Comment: @JonHarding If you don't load it, you won't be able to access it either, so whatever part of your code is getting the property's value is doing so seemingly uselessly. That said, `.AsNoTracking` *without* the `.Include` should do the trick.

Comment: @hvd you're trying to access the Group though and the context is disposed. Either remove the using or use the Include as in the answer